# How to hold binary data in matlab and perform hex conversion

Tags: matlab, hex, binary-data

I want to hold some binary data in a variable in matlab for example

> 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1

Later I want to convert it to hex like this

> F1

I am unable to identify that how to hold binary data in a variable and is there a function perform that conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this, assuming `a` as the input binary row vector -

```
%// Pad zeros to make number of binary bits in input as multiple of 4
a = [zeros(1,4-mod(numel(a)-1,4)-1) a];

%// Convert to string, then to binary and finally to hex number as a char array
out = dec2hex(bin2dec(num2str(reshape(a,4,[])','%1d')))'
```

Note that there are **no restrictions** in it for the number of binary elements in the input vector. So, as a random `1 x 291` sized input binary data, the output was -

```
out =
02678E51063A7FFBD9CE1DF6A3DC63B17F71C39C17DC499AD58516D7B571FC58DF05957F7
```

Comment: If I want to do this operation only on a single vector

Comment: @User1551892 Then use `a` use directly, where `a` would be your single vector.

Comment: Thanks. Now it can work any arbitrary long binary number

Comment: Have you tried very long vector using this method ?

Comment: @User1551892 What do you mean by long vector, how long? I don't think there should be any problem.

Comment: This method only works if binary values are less than 52 bits. In my case, I am trying calculate the hex for vector containing 57 1's and 0's

Comment: Now, this approach works for even longer vector. I've examined it for 100 of length vector a and  gives the same result with `binaryVectorToHex()`. For information purposes (only)...

Comment: @mehmet Exactly! I did the same to double-check! Hope mathworks guys don't sue us now ;)

Comment: Thanks alot for both of you in order to help me. Have a nice time.

Comment: It would be better to use `zeros(1,4-mod(numel(a)-1,4)-1)` in the first line. That way you avoid adding `4` unnecessary zeros when `numel(a)` is already a multiple of `4`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you! That was an issue for sure there.

Comment: @Divakar I meant replace only the `zeros()` part. It should be `a = [zeros(1,4-mod(numel(a)-1,4)-1) a]`

Comment: @LuisMendo Ops, me being sloppy there!!

Answer (score 2):

There are MATLAB built in functions for your case: [`logical()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html) and [`binaryVectorToHex()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/daq/ref/binaryvectortohex.html), but, *Data Acquisition Toolbox* is needed for `binaryVectorToHex()`.

Try this:

```
>> vec    = randi(2, 1, 100) - 1;      %// Double type vector
>> vecBin = logical(vec);              %// Binary conversion
>> vecHex = binaryVectorToHex(vecBin); %// Hexadecimal conversion
```

Comment: I do not have data acquisition tool kit. Therefore I can not access method binaryVectorHex method

Comment: No keep it. Because it can help some one.

Comment: Looks like an useful function actually!

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I had forgotten about futher visitor because of same problem.

Answer (score 2):

A possibly faster approoach, which makes use of the fact that exactly four binary digits make up a hex digit:

```
x = [zeros(1,4-mod(numel(x)-1,4)-1) x]; %// make length a multiple of 4
k = 2.^(3:-1:0); %// used for converting each group of 4 bits into a number
m = '0123456789ABCDEF'; %// map from those numbers to hex digits
result = m(k*reshape(x,4,[])+1); %// convert each 4 bits into a number and apply map
```